# How to convert this table into one row table?

Tags: mysql

I have a very simple static table:

```
type     qty
A         10
B         20
C         30
```

I'd like to convert this table into one row result. I use this query:

```
SELECT type, 
   CASE WHEN type = 'A' THEN qty END AS 'A',
   CASE WHEN type = 'B' THEN qty END AS 'B',
   CASE WHEN type = 'C' THEN qty END AS 'C'
FROM mytable
GROUP BY type
```

The result is:

```
 type     A      B        C
   A     10     NULL      NULL
   B    NULL    20        NULL    
   C    NULL    NULL      30
```

my desired output:

```
 A    B    C
10   20   30
```

Comment: You'll have to `SUM()` that. Why not just `GROUP BY` and do the transformation in your application code?

Comment: i have to get the desired output through mySQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have one more column to transpose this using max() or sum() and group by. If you are grouping by Type, we get separate sets for each of 'A', 'B' and 'C', so we see separate rows.

example:

```
id Type Quantity
1  A    10
1  B    20
1  C    30
```

The query below would work with both MySQL 5.7(ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode) and 5.6 as well. (Tested with v5.7.18 default settings.)

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN Type = 'A' THEN qty
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS A,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN Type = 'B' THEN qty
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS B,
    MAX(CASE
        WHEN Type = 'C' THEN qty
        ELSE NULL
    END) AS C
FROM
    myTable
GROUP BY id;
```

where as this one fails with MySQL 5.7(ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode)

```
Select id, Type from MyTable group by id;
```